# How can I color Metro RichEditBox selection?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I can not make part of my text "red".

```
  //this.RTF = RichEditBox
  this.RTF.IsColorFontEnabled = true;
  this.RTF.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "some text");
  this.RTF.Document.Selection.StartPosition = 0;
  this.RTF.Document.Selection.EndPosition = 4;
  //nope: this.RTF.Document.Selection.FormattedText.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
  this.RTF.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
  this.RTF.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Strikethrough = Windows.UI.Text.FormatEffect.On;
  this.RTF.Document.Selection.EndPosition = 0;
```

I tried background, it worked, trying strikethrough in the sample too, works... googling for this does not - or I missed the right questio for the answer.

If anyone else struggled with this and knows how to do this, please help!

Comment: IsColorFontEnabled, per the documentation, only affects emoji with colour information built-in.

Comment: In what way does your existing code not work? What behaviour are you looking for? When I run your code snippet I get what I expect: "some" in red-strikethrough and "text" in the default black.